# Splashscreen does not work on iphone 6 & 6 plus in portrait mode

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen, iphone-6, ios8.3

I am trying to get a splashscreen in **portrait mode** for iphone 6 & iphone 6 plus. I have the images of `750x1334` & `1242 x 2208`  with names `Default-667h@2x.png` and `Default-736h@3x.png` respectively. I am not adding the landscape mode splashscreens for any of the iphone sizes. All other iphone splashscreens seem to work except the iphone 6 & 6 plus. The iphone **OS version is 8.3**. It is a cordova app. I also tried using **org.apache.cordova.splashscreen plugin**.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The server moved for sourcing the plugin. Upgrade your Cordova package and get your plugin from NPM. NOTE: you may need to move your plugin version back at least on version. I have seen problems using the current plugin and iOS9. Also, You may need to start your app from scratch.

From: [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Summary from #11

- NEW NEW [Cordova npm search page](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/)
- NEW NEW [Cordova CORE plugins](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/plugins/pluginapis.html)
- [Latest version of plugins](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/06/22/plugins-release.html) June 22, 2015